# Calling Module function from jQuery and Ajax

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

With every drupal site I make, I usually create a custom module that I use to hold different php functions and other things custom to the site I am working on. It usually only consists of a module_name.module and module_name.info. Additionally, I always have .js file in the theme to do any javascripts I might need. Pretty standard right? But I have now run into a situation where I need the two to talk to one another.

I know you can call a .php file and pass it data using .ajax in jquery. How would I envoke a function written in my custom module from the js file in my theme?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help -- got this code from a Lullabot module development training.

It all revolves around a hook_menu callback.  The value in 'page callback' is the function that will be called, in this case it is: "**menu_magic_page**"

So Drupal looks for the menu_magic_page() function.

Your jQuery / AJAX call would then reference the value what's in $items['X'] where X is "**magic**" here.  So hitting http://example.com/magic would run the module function "**menu_magic_page**"

FWIW: the type/MENU_CALLBACK ensures it doesn't get added to menu's etc.  It just ensures Drupal is ready to process it.

Hope this helps.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function menu_magic_menu() {
  $items = array();

  /**
   * This is a simple callback.
   *
   * This will create a path at http://example.com/magic. When visited, that
   * URL will trigger the "menu_magic_page" function.
   */

  $items['magic'] = array(
    'title' => 'Menu Magic!',
    'page callback' => 'menu_magic_page',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );


/**
 * Page callback for 'magic'. This is the function that will get called
 * everytime a user visits http://example.com/magic.
 */
function menu_magic_page() {
  global $user;
  return t('Hello, @username!', array('@username' => $user->name));
}
```

Comment: I am using this in ajax             $.ajax({
                url: 'magic',
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    //Do something here with the "data"
                    alert(data);
                }
            }); which is actuly returning me the HTML in alert rather the user name being return by this functions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather I see RETURN is not working in 'menu_magic_page' but print.